# Route behaviour when the user is authenticated and not authenticated in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I'm implementing a GET request like below. This route allows anonymous access, but I want to give more sensitive information when the user is authenticated.

```
[Controller]
/*
 * @Route ("/api/item/{code}.{_format}", name="api.item.get", defaults={"_format"="json"}})
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_API, IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY")
 */
public function getItemAction(Request $request, $code)
{
    /* @var UsernamePasswordToken $token */
    $token = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
    $user = $token->getUser();

    // snip
}

[security.yml]
    - { path: '^/?api/items/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+', role: [ROLE_API, IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] }
```

I'm expecting the $user is a User object when the user is authenticated but it's a string type and the value is "anon.". What am I missing?

Comment: "anon." mean the user is not logged in. And your route allow unauthenticated user so why are you surprised ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't try it since I don't have symfony 2.8 anymore (side note: you should seriously consider updating your version!) but have you tried something like this?

```
if ($user instanceof User) {
    // fetch those sensitive info
}
```